# How to properly implement error handling in async/await case

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, async-await

I use async/await ecma6 standard without any custom library.

I don't get at the moment how I can properly catch and throw errors.
I have multiple async/await functions and if somewhere down below an critical error happens I want to throw the error to the top and of all async functions and stop execution of the function.

I tried to throw exceptions out of the async/await function and catch it in the target function but I get a error in node.js:

```
    this.basicAuthLogin= async function(user)
{
    "use strict";
    const login = new Login(this.host, this.url, user, user.pw);

    //getSessionID throws error
    this.sessionID = getSessionID(result.request.response);
}
```

> (node:13964) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise
>   rejection (rejection id: 1): Error: getSessionID response is undefined
>   (node:13964) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise
>   rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are
>   not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit
>   code. Debugger attached.

So it seems I am not allowed to throw exceptions out of async functions or even rethrow it in the catch block of the promise in node.js?

So how do I get this working? 
Am I supposed to catch the error in the async function and return the error in the promise and rethrow then out of the async function?

```
   this.basicAuthLogin= async function(user)
{
    "use strict";
    const login = new Login(this.host, this.url, user, user.pw);
   try{
    //getSessionID throws error
    this.sessionID = getSessionID(result.request.response);
   } catch(err) { return err;}
}
```

But this would mean that in my call stack from the first async function every function needs be async and I have to await the promise even though I don't really need it.

I hope somebody can enlighten me.

Regards
Ruvi

Edit basic call stack pseudo code:

```
   async startTest[arr]{

    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
    {
      try {
          await runStep(arr[i];
        } catch(err) { 
            console.log(err);
            break; 
        }
      }
    }

  async runStep(step)
  {
     try {
     var userIsValid = await validateUser(step.user);
     var req = buildRequest(step.request);
     var result = await sendRequest(req);
     var verify = verifyResult();
     } catch(err){ throw err;}
  }

  async validateUser(user)
  {
     //make checks
     //
     var result = await this.authenticate(parameter).catch(err => {throw err});
     userFound = true;
   }

  function authenticate(parameter) {
  //can throw async function
   basicAuthLogin(parameter).catch(err => {throw err};

   }

  function async basicAuthLogin(parameter()
  {
   try {
    //can throw  async function
      var result = await request(parameter);
      //can throw sync function
      this.sessionID = getSessionID(response);
      //can throw   sync function
      } catch(err) { throw err; }
   }
```

Comment: Is `getSessionID` async? Either because it's `async` or because it returns a promise?

Comment: No it is not async it is a simple function that throws an exception that I want to catch 5 or 6 floors up the call stack but it seems I am not allowed to do that.

Comment: `getSessionID response is undefined ` I think you should make sure response is defined

Comment: @Ruvi: Thanks. Since nothing in `basicAuthLogin` is asynchronous, why is it an `async` function?

Comment: Please fix the indentation to make examples easier to read, downvoting for now.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

One of the great things about `async`/`await` is that they enable `try`/`catch` to work with your asynchronous code.

Your first `basicAuthLogin` function is absolutely fine (provided `getSessionID` is a *synchronous* function; <s>if it isn't, you're missing an `await`</s> *[you've now said it is]*). The code *using* `basicAuthLogin` must handle the possibility it will throw (either by handling the error or allowing it to propagate to its caller, which is responsible for handling it). So either:

```
// In an `async` function
try {
    await this.basicAuthLogin(/*...*/);
} catch (e) {
    // Handle the fact something failed
}
```

or

```
// NOT in an `async` function:
this.basicAuthLogin(/*...*/)
    .catch(e => { /* Handle the fact something failed */ });
```

If the code using it does one of those two things (or lets the error propagate to code that does one of those two things), you won't get the "Unhandled rejection" error.

In response to my comment asking if `getSessionID` was asynchronous, you wrote:

> No it is not async it is a simple function that throws an exception that I want to catch 5 or 6 floors up the call stack but it seems I am not allowed to do that.

**Here's a live example** of doing that (in my case, I've made `basicAuthLogin` actually use something asynchronous prior to `getSessionID`, but it doesn't really matter):

```js
const getSessionID = () => {
  throw new Error("Failed");
};
const somethingAsync = () => new Promise(resolve => {
  setTimeout(resolve, 100);
});
const basicAuthLogin = async function(user)
{
    "use strict";
    await somethingAsync();
    /*
    const login = new Login(this.host, this.url, user, user.pw);
    */

    //getSessionID throws error
    getSessionID();
};

const wrapper1 = async () => {
  await basicAuthLogin();
};
const wrapper2 = async () => {
  await wrapper1();
};
const wrapper3 = async () => {
  await wrapper2();
};

// Top-level caller
(async () => {
  try {
    await wrapper3();
  } catch (e) {
    console.log("Caught error: " + e.message);
  }
})();
```

The rule is just like it is with exceptions (because notionally these *are* exceptions):

1. Either handle it (e.g., `try`/`catch`), or let it propagate to the caller (typically by not doing anything at all), and
2. The top level MUST handle it

That Rule #2 means that when you transition from non-`async` code to `async` code (typically right at the top of your stack), you need a wrapper. Either:

```
(async () => {
  try {
    await theFirstAsyncFunction();
    await theNextAsyncFunction();
    await aThirdAsyncFunction();
  } catch (e) {
    // handle the error
  }
})();
```

or

```
(async () => {
  await theFirstAsyncFunction();
  await theNextAsyncFunction();
  await aThirdAsyncFunction();
})().catch(e => { /* handle the error */});
```

or of course:

```
theFirstAsyncFunction()
.then(() => theNextAsyncFunction())
.then(() => aThirdAsyncFunction())
.catch(e => { /* handle the error */});
```

The common denominator there is: The top level always handles the error.

Comment: Thank you very much for the very detailed answer.
So I have two options chain the promise results with a wrapper or 
rethrow the exception on every level?
Because the last seemed not to work on my code example that I added.

Comment: @Ruvi: No, there's no need at all to re-throw on every level, that would have been an exceptionally bad design for `async`/`await`. Look at the runnable example in the answer: None of `wrapper1`, `wrapper2`, `wrapper3`, and `basicAuthLogin` are bothered with error handling at all, they just do their work; the error from `getSessionID` propagates through them automatically, just as with non-`async` code.