# How to handle error in async/await function?

Tags: node.js

I have a function like this:

```
async getPatient(patientId: string): Promise<PatientDTO> {
    const patient = await PatientDAO.getPatients({ id: patientId })

    if (patient.length === 0) {
        throw new NotFoundError("Patient Not Found!")
    }

    return patient[0]
}
```

But I got an error
`UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Patient Not Found!`

This happened cause I have used `async` function. How can I make this code running properly?

Comment: How is `PatientDAO.getPatients` implemented?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to properly implement error handling in async/await case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48685872/how-to-properly-implement-error-handling-in-async-await-case)

Comment: @ManuelSpigolon just for getting data from server using fetch

Comment: @roy for my case, PatientDAO not trowed any error, I was used custom error if the function return empty array

Answer (score 1):

In order to manage errors in an `async` function, you have to use a `try/catch` block:

```
async getPatient(patientId: string): Promise<PatientDTO> {
    try {
      const patient = await PatientDAO.getPatients({ id: patientId })

      return patient[0]
    } catch (error) {
        // Do whatever you may want with error
        throw error;
    }
    
}
```

I should mention, that if you simply want to throw the error thats received from `getPatients` theres no need for a `try/catch` block at all. Its only needed if you wish to modify the error or perform an extra action according to the error that was thrown.

Comment: It's just return null

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options:
First one is try/catch block with `await` keyword. Please notice that `await` has to be used in `async` function.

```js
try {
    const patient = await getPatient(foo);
    // handle your data here
} catch(e) {
    // error handling here
}
```

Second one is `catch` function

```js
getPatient(foo)
    .then(patient => {
        // handle your data here
    }).catch(error => {
        // error handling here
    });
```

Comment: In this case I want to check if patient exist in my database, I throw the Error if function return empty array. I tried for the first code but not working.